# What creates target directory in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to set up debugging by this article:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-and-debug-a-spring-boot-application-using-docker-compose.html#35ea56fc

it works for me on the application from the article but does not work on real application.

I have noticed the difference is - in real application there is no target directory.

But in the article there is a line:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /project/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

so I assume it expects target directory. I do not see the demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar file in the demo application. Is it created temporarily and deleted?

I see there is no target directory in the repository so something creates it - what? https://github.com/IdeaUJetBrains/SpringBootDockerDemoDebug

And probably this might be one of reasons why code does not stop at breakpoints?

And also how it works at all? Why there is project directory before target directory but project directory is not created and it still works in demo application?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html. IntelliJ IDEA creates artifacts from Maven/Gradle projects automatically. They are usually placed in the target directory. Make sure artifacts are configured and you actually build them.

Comment: that is interesting. In the article the was not written how to configure articafts, and I just opened project structure of that applicaiton, there is no Artifacts configured but somehow the target folder exists. So do I really need to configure it if in the article it was not shown how to?

Comment: Try `mvn package`, you can run it from the IDE: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html.