# Intellij java building artifacts for debugger java: package does not exist

Tags: java, spring, debugging, intellij-idea

Trying to set up debugger for spring aplication. Based on the comment from this [What creates target directory in spring boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832324/what-creates-target-directory-in-spring-boot-application)
I might need artifacts.
I do not know hot to set up the artifacts for spring boot application, so trying to set up by cmd application article https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-a-java-application-using-a-dockerfile.html

I did not set Main class, because I have no idea what is main class in my project. I tried searching function main() but did not find it. So I had set up:
[image]

Running Build > Build Artifacts and choosing my jar artifact, I get

/home/agmis/projects/openelis/src/main/java/org/openelisglobal/dataexchange/fhir/FhirUtil.java:4:46
java: package org.itech.fhir.dataexport.core.service does not exist

I think there is high chance that this part of code works, because I have been debuging related code, seen that function. So I am just probably getting this error when building artifacts. And the function is modified on April 5 this year, so this also adds the confidence that this part of code works.

[image]

I see interface is in red, and import is grey so because IDE also does not see it.

So how to fix that?

Also if you can give a link to a good tutorial on how to setup debugger with docker which would solve me this problem and maybe I would not even get this error, this could make the problem solved also.

**Update**

Based on Renato "Reload All Maven Projects" - did not help, same problem still.

Comment: Try to "Reload All Maven Projects"

Comment: You need a fat jar for your app, refer to https://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot.